# Google Maps Api directions: функция подсчета расстояния срабатывает через раз

Tags: google-maps-api, google-spreadsheet

Есть Google Sheet, отчет о поездках, в несколько столбцов: координаты места отправления, координаты места назначения и итоговый столбец, который считает расстояние (на автомобиле) между этими точками на карте. Функция для подсчета расстояния такая:

```
function DrivingDistance(origin, dest) {

  var originParsed = origin.split(",");
  var destParsed = dest.split(",");

  var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
    .setOrigin(originParsed[0],originParsed[1])
    .setDestination(destParsed[0],destParsed[1])
    .setMode(Maps.DirectionFinder.Mode.DRIVING)
    .getDirections();

  if (directions.routes != undefined && directions.routes[0] != undefined) {
    var distValue = directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
    Logger.Log(distalue);
    return distValue;
    }
  else
    return "cannot calculate the distance"

}
```

Она срабатывает через раз: запускаю - считает верно, запускаю второй раз - directions.routes оказывается undefined и ничего не выдается. Между запусками - никаких изменений в коде, просто подряд пару раз запускал.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы расстояние считалось всегда - и желательно верно?))

Спасибо.